# Force 2 decimal place format in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select * from MyTable;
+----+--------+
| id | Va     |
+----+--------+
|  1 | 77.218 |
|  2 | 34.43  |
|  3 |   909  |
+----+--------+
```

How do I update column Va to force both a permanent (1) round and (2) format to 2 d.p

Va is datatype FLOAT

This isn’t working:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Va=FORMAT(ROUND(Va,2),2);
```

i.e. to: select *:

```
+--------------+
| 77.22        |
| 34.43        |
| 909.00       |
+--------------+
```

It is just leaving 909 at the bottom and not 909.00
Thanks for any help

**Full Detail**

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
def exe(_input):
    mycursor.execute(_input)
exe("USE olbliss$CCE")
exe("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable")
exe('''CREATE TABLE MyTable
(id INT(6) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
Va FLOAT(30) NOT NULL)''')
exe("INSERT INTO MyTable (Va) VALUES ('77.218');")
exe("INSERT INTO MyTable (Va) VALUES ('34.43');")
exe("INSERT INTO MyTable (Va) VALUES ('909');")
exe("UPDATE MyTable SET Va=FORMAT(ROUND(Va,2),2);")
```

```
mysql> select * from MyTable;
+----+-------+
| id | Va    |
+----+-------+
|  1 | 77.22 |
|  2 | 34.43 |
|  3 |   909 |
+----+-------+
```

Comment: Didn't you say the column was called `Va` not `DR`

Comment: apologies, copying error. updated now. cheers

Comment: What DataType is the `Va` column please

Comment: And in what way does it NOT WORK? Thats not a very helpful descriptions as it could mean a number of things from database crash to calcing the wrong value

Comment: Also not sure what "permanent (1) round" actually means

Comment: Best to show us an example of what you want the results to be in an example of all cases

Comment: Please see question. There is an example of what I would like.

Comment: Well when I run that code I get what you wanted to get. So what do you get that is wrong

Comment: *Va is datatype FLOAT* a float value is unformatted. You can format it with format() in a query.

Comment: If you want to store formatted numeric values then change the data type of Va to VARCHAR.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, please see “Full Detail” section added to the question.

Comment: I think that is probably just because it will not show unnecessary decimal places and `.00` is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fixed number of digits of scale, use `DECIMAL(5,2)` instead of FLOAT.

You can have greater precision, for example `DECIMAL(9,2)`. I chose (5,2) in the example above because it was sufficient for the values you showed in your question.

Read more about it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fixed-point-types.html

Comment: I think it is wisely to give according ALTER TABLE statement...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `FORMAT(909, 2)` and then the output will be `909.00`.

So, then your statement will become:

`Select id, FORMAT(Va, 2) from MyTable;`